# JS (document.getElementById("example").textContent) doesn't show content in var

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

when i try to show a live chart using content of id load2
it doesn't return anything but when i put the textContent in the console log
it does show numbers what am i doing wrong?

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second

                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
                         var   y =  (document.getElementById("load2").textContent);
                        console.log(document.getElementById("load2").textContent);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -50; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: 0
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
    });
});
```

this load2 element is coming from a JSON pull request

Comment: console.log() executes on runtime , probably at the moment you assign "y" the DOM element you are trying to access (load2) has not yet been rendered.

Comment: could you post a bit of the surrounding code? since your problem can't be reproduced with the two given lines. interesting would be a bit of the markup as well as the place where the variable y is defined/used.

Comment: You need to fix your question as you have no sample output, the script has no context and we don't know what you're using to output a "live chart". However, if I had to guess it would be because the live chart is instantiated before "load2" has any content. That, or textContent doesn't contain valid data.

Comment: edited the JS code

Comment: could it be that highcharts validates the parameter types in `addPoint` and dismisses the `y` because it's a string rather than an int(or float)? you could test this by using `y =  parseInt(document.getElementById("load2").textContent))`.

Comment: Thank you very much @garglblarg parseFloat(document.getElementById("load2").textContent); fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highcharts validates the parameter types in addPoint and dismisses the y because it's a string rather than an int or float

use the `parseFloat` or `ParseInt`.

parseFloat(document.getElementById("load2").textContent);